# Error:(2, 0) Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet

Tags: android, kotlin

I recently Upgrade My android studio to 3.0.1 When i try to create the new project i get the below error My code runs fine on older version i also upgrade the Gradle Plugin

**Error**

```
Error:(2, 0) Unable to find method 

'org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/gradle/api/internal/file/FileResolver;)V'. Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) <a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem. <a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

**Build Gradle File**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assemble
```

And see if that helps? Also in your dependencies make sure to change `compile` to `implementation`, recommended as of Gradle 3

Comment: I missed `compile` -> `implementation`. Thanks.